# Trying to assign property until the setter stops throwing the exception

Tags: c#, error-handling

Can I improve this code and make it more beautiful? For example, `for` expressions in ReadConsole method is ugly for me.

```cs
string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    { 
        // Only letters, whitespaces and '-' are avaiable
        if (value.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || new string(" -").Contains(c)))
            _name = value;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Oops!");
    }
}
internal void ReadConsole()
{
    for (bool success=false; success == false;)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Name (only letter, spaces or dash): ");
        try
        {
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it by using a `private` method to validate the input, if true, would set the `Name` property to the input and return true, otherwise false. Next, declare a `private readonly char[]` to include the allowed chars. Then use `while` loop instead of `for`.

This is how it would be :

```
private static readonly char[] _allowedChars = new char[] { ' ', '-' };

public string Name { get; set; }

internal void ReadConsole()
{
    Console.Write("Enter Name (only letter, spaces or dash): ");

    while (!TryParseName(Console.ReadLine()))
    {
        Console.Write("Wrong input, please re-enter Name (only letter, spaces or dash): ");
    }
}

private bool TryParseName(string input)
{
    try
    {
        if(input?.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || _allowedChars.Contains(c)) == true)
        {
            Name = input;
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `TryParseName` <-> `TrySetName`

Comment: @Heslacher ops, nice catche ;). I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your question in two parts. The first, I'll answer your question:

```
internal void ReadConsole()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Name (only letter, spaces or dash): ");
        try
        {
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Ask you can see, I've removed the verbose `for` and replaced it with a more idiomatic C# infinite loop. Then when the input is valid, it will simply `return` from the method.

The second part: I'm not sure I'd put that style of validation in the setter. It might be better to have a Validator pattern on the object which contains the `Name` as a whole and call that as necessary. This facilitates separation of concerns. Below is an example of a validator with your logic implemented. You call it after you set a property, or group of properties. So, just a thought.

```
public class NameClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidator<T>
{
    void Validate(T data);
}

public class NameClassValidator : IValidator<NameClass>
{
     public void Validate(NameClass data)
     {
        if (!data.Name.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || new string(" -").Contains(c)))
            throw new ArgumentException("Oops!");
     }
}
```